# What is the way to correctly build toolbar with hamburger on react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

What is the best way to make a toolbar with a hamburger and search (icon) with some drawer effect on the top of the screen for iOS and Android accordingly on react-native?

Answer (score 0):

React native has bridged the toolbar and the drawer layout from android so you can use both of them with no problem. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html If you want to build you app also for iOS I would take a look at React navigation witch mining’s native behavior and is cross platform.